# How dispatch Events in event loop to subscribers?

Tags: c++, templates, events, polymorphism

I try to achieve an asynchronous event loop which can store events in a queue and dispatches them later to different subscribers. All events are derived from one base, also all subscribers are derived from their own base class. Events should hold different types of values. Subscribers shall forward them to instances of other classes. I can only use std library.

I have problems to dispatch events of different types to the proper methods of the subscriber sub class. If I store Event Base in the queue, I lose type information of the derived events and cannot call the proper methods of the subscriber. I also do not want to use `If then else` or `switch` on type Info.

I tried using templates and create for every event its own dispatch method in the subscriber class or `std::function` to wrap the method call in a lambda function.

My approach seams utterly complicated and slow. I cannot forward the events to the classes managed by the subscriber. I always get error no matching function call. I understand why but have no idea how to solve my problem.

Usage:

```
observer obs;
EventLoop<observer,Event> el;

auto f = [&obs] (Event& e) {
    obs.dispatch((Up&)e);
};
el.subscribe<Up>(f);

auto g = [&obs] (belfsm::Event& e) {
    obs.dispatch((Down&)e);
};

el.subscribe<Down>(g);

Up a;
Down b;
el.sendEvent(a);
el.sendEvent(b);
el.dispatchF();
```

What I tried so far:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <typeindex>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

template<typename T_Subscribe, typename T_Event>
class EventLoop {
public:      
    typedef std::function<void(T_Event&)> eventHandler;

    EventLoop(){}
    virtual ~EventLoop(){}

    void dispatch2subscriber(){
        while(!eventQueue.empty()){
            std::type_index eventType = eventQueue.front().first;

            auto it_s = eventSubscriber.find(eventType);
            if( it_s != eventSubscriber.end() ){
                std::vector<T_Subscribe*> v = eventSubscriber[eventType];

                for(auto const& subscriber: v) {
                    subscriber->dispatch(eventQueue.front().second);
                }
        }

        eventQueue.pop();
    }

    void dispatchFunction(){
        while(!eventQueue.empty()){
            std::type_index eventType = eventQueue.front().first;

            auto it_s = eventSubscriberF.find(eventType);
            if( it_s != eventSubscriberF.end() ){
                std::vector<std::function<void(T_Event&)>> v = eventSubscriberF[eventType];

                for(auto const& subscriber: v) {
                    subscriber(eventQueue.front().second);
                }
            }

            eventQueue.pop();
        }//while
    }

    template<typename U>
    bool subscribe(T_Subscribe& subscriber){
        std::type_index eventType = getEventType<U>();
        eventSubscriber[eventType].push_back(&subscriber);
        return true;
    }



    template<typename U>
    bool subscribe(eventHandler subscriber){
        std::type_index eventType = getEventType<U>();

        eventSubscriberF[eventType].push_back(subscriber);
        return true;
}
private:
    //Event Queue
    std::queue<std::pair<std::type_index,T_Event&>std::deque<std::pair<std::type_index,T_Event&>>> eventQueue;
    //Subscriber map pointer to instance
    std::map<std::type_index,std::vector<T_Subscribe*>> eventSubscriber;
    //Subscriber map to member function
    std::map<std::type_index,std::vector< eventHandler > > eventSubscriberF;
}
```

Subscribers:

```
//Events
struct Event {};
struct Up : Event { int i };
struct Down : Event { int i };

//Class which uses events.
class another_class
{
   void react(Event &) {};
}

class yet_another_class : public another_class 
{
    void react(Event &) {};
    void react(Up &) {};
    void react(Down &) {};
}

//Manages other classes which uses events
class BaseSubscribery
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<another_class> another_class_ptr;
}

class Subscriber: public BaseSubscriber
{
public:
    observer();
    template<typename E>
    void dispatch(E& event);

};

template<typename E>
void observer::dispatch(E& event) {
    *another_class_ptr->react(event);*
}
```

Comment: You should work with pointers to `another_class` interface in queue so the call to `react` is handled through the `vtable` and thus not losing type data.

Comment: @Manuel I used subscriber class because `another_class_ptr` can change to another instance and make the dispatch call illegal.

How would I achieve your suggestion? I cannot overload virtual methods in `yet_another_class` or use templated virtual methods . If I use templated `react` methods in `another_class`, lambdas always call Base class methods, not derived ones. I'm a bit lost here.

Answer (score 0):

This code shows how to handle object inherited from a common parent and `dynamic_cast` to derived one.

There is one base interface: `event`
There are three event types: `event_one`, `event_two` and `event_no`. Their topology is as follows:

event_two -> event_one -> event

So `event_two` inherits from `event_one` which inherits from `event`.
And there is an `event_no` ("no" because it will be unhandled) which inherits directly from `event`.

event_no -> event

We create a event handler and pass all derived events to it.

The key part is `if (dynamic_cast<event_one *>(ievent))` in `handler_one::handle_event`, if there is no run-time conversion to derived class, this will return a null pointer, so you know you can't handle it. In other case it will return the derived class you want.
You should have a chain of derived classes, most derived first, to handle all cases correctly.

I've created two handlers, one partial (`handler_one`) which handles two event types: `event_one` and `event_two` (`event_two` isn't in the `if` but as it is an `event_one` it will be handled and the correct function called; if you don't define `guid` function, in the derived, the one in `event_one` will be called); and a second one (`handler_two`) which handles them all.

As for the queues, you may store `event` pointers and forget about derived classes.

EDIT:

Now it is managed by templates. No `if` or `switch`.
You can add other event types specializing a member template.

The output from the program:

```sh
manuel@desktop:~/projects$ g++ -Wall main.cc -o main -std=c++11 && ./main 
Handler 1
Event guid: abcd (id=1)
Event guid: abcd with some custom stuff (id=2)
Event no guid: ugh! this is unhandled (id=-1)
End
```

The program:

```
//
#include <typeindex>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class event
{
public:
    event () : _id (0) {}
    virtual ~event () {}
    virtual int id () { return _id; }
protected:
    int _id;
};

class event_one : public event
{
public:
    event_one () : _guid ("abcd") { _id = 1; }
    ~event_one () {}
    virtual std::string guid () { return _guid; }
protected:
    std::string _guid;
};

class event_two : public event_one
{
public:
    event_two () { _id = 2; }
    ~event_two () {}
    virtual std::string guid () { return _guid + " with some custom stuff"; }
protected:
};

class event_no : public event
{
public:
    event_no () : _guid ("ugh!") { _id = -1; }
    ~event_no () {}
    virtual std::string guid_no () { return _guid + " this is unhandled"; }
protected:
    std::string _guid;
};

class handler_one
{
public:
    template<typename Event>
    int handle_event (Event * ievent);
};

template<typename Event>
int handler_one::handle_event (Event * ievent) {
    std::cout << "Event guid: " << ievent->guid()
              << " (id=" << ievent->id() << ")" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

template<>
int handler_one::handle_event<event_no> (event_no * ievent) {
    std::cout << "Event no guid: " << ievent->guid_no()
              << " (id=" << ievent->id() << ")" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main (void)
{
    event_one eo;
    event_two et;
    event_no en;
    handler_one ho;

    std::cout << "Handler 1" << std::endl;
    ho.handle_event (&eo);
    ho.handle_event (&et);
    ho.handle_event (&en);

    std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort to help, I really appreciated it. Unfortunately, I wanted to avoid the if then else or switch statements. I was looking into CRTP but could not figure out, how to use it for my problem.

Comment: @T.bur I've changed the code to do it with templates.